# Setup outlook 2013 for multiple mail accounts

Tags: outlook, outlook-2013

I know that we can setup multiple emails in outlook 2013, but my client want outlook to prompt password when opening and when he enter his email and password it should login able to access his email. 
When he use another email it should work like that.

Please tell me whether its possible or not

Comment: The current forum is for developers. I'd recommend asking non-programming questions on the http://www.superuser.com site instead.

Answer (score -1):

Please see the following link.  Depending on how you want it set up, you can either have multiple "accounts" under a single profile, or multiple profiles on a machine/user login.  This will give you both alternatives and how you can set them up.

https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Switch-to-another-Outlook-e-mail-profile-be3b617f-3f64-43d3-9037-8313b431803c#bm3

To get **exactly** the functionality you are asking:

- Go to Mail settings as shown in the link.
- Add your profiles (one per email)
- Underneath the add buttons, you should have two radio buttons, select:"Prompt for a profile to be used"
- Click Apply
- Click properties
- In the popup window Click the "E-mail Accounts..." button and go to the "Data Files" tab.

For each account/file:

- Double Click on the line
- go to the security tab
- select "Always prompt for logon credentials.
- Click OK

This will ask you which profile each time you launch outlook, as well as prompting for credentials.

Comment: The anonymous downvoter may not be downvoting answering an off-topic question but the content of the answer.  "You can't password-protect a profile..." Crabby's guide to Outlook profiles versus e-mail accounts https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/Crabbys-guide-to-Outlook-profiles-versus-e-mail-accounts-a1480690-1190-411f-a55d-a8b5e88269f7?CorrelationId=fbc19c75-e33f-4557-b906-f201815a196c&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: Well... you can:
[https://support.office.microsoft.com/...](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/Set-a-password-to-help-protect-your-Outlook-information-f60fb0e7-f0ad-4d7c-858b-9619d1b9f0b6?CorrelationId=89d3a859-93ae-435d-af1d-3ec26444f260&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)
   By password protecting the outlook data file when you choose the applicable profile that it attaches to, it will require the password in order to access any data.  inherently password protecting your outlook profile.   The requestor in this instance, wanted to password protect the email access; which this WILL do.